# Check file in binary or ASCII format in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I read a file in action script that kind of files maybe in ASCII or binary format.

How can i check which format is used when read?

regards.

Comment: You can’t. ASCII is just a binary format too which happens to be readable by text editors which interpret every byte as ASCII characters. You could just guess, either on the content or on the file extension.

Comment: the file extension is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the byte values from the file and try to make the guesses based on the byte values that you read. If you read a lot of bytes with values from 65-128 (approximately), it's very likely a "ASCII" format. Check [www.asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com) and pick the ascii codes that you expect will and will not appear in an ASCII/binary file.